# From microcontrollers to microprocessors [Embedded Devices]

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, microprocessor, linux, soc

I was told by some developer that embedded controllers are task specific devices that requires low latency which processor based devices can't offer due to OS overhead.

So I would like to first of all confirm the correctness of this statement.

Secondly, what is the "level of sophistication" which mandates use of processors with an operating system. I know this can be broad as it is difficult to define "level of sophistication" so a specific example or two might help.

Inorder to not get penalized, I can narrow it down by asking:
Can the basics of functionality such as web surfing device be designed purely using microcontrollers without OS?
And since web surfing device must take user input, communicate over the internet, output to the display, output to the audio etc, can such level of sophistication be achieved by writing mere firmwares and using micro controllers? (barebone programming)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to be careful with terms, embedded devices.  Your smart phone is an embedded device so is a set top box, a game console, etc.  And these days these can all surf the net.

Also it is more than possible to surf the net without an operating system.  Doesnt matter the system, you can write bare metal code for your desktop/laptop to complete this task.  There is a well known IP stack that is used by bare metal developers to get over that hurdle, simply due to the rules of those protocols and getting them right.

I dont find the notion of microcontrollers if that is what you were implying being low latency as most devlopers use vendor libraries and/or libraries on top of an OS, adding a significant amount of latency and bloat and overhead and...

They may happen to end up being low latency as a side effect not a design goal.  you have flash and ram on board, there are countless tradeoffs between cost and size and performance in these designs.  low latency is not their primary goal they could do better if it were.

Relative to certain cpu architectures with caches and slow dram and such, sure an mcu is fast.  But some of those architectures as implemented can easily outrun an mcu, depends on the implementation.

Sadly there are chips in the mcu class that are becoming hard to distinguish from full blown cpus.  They have caches and mmus (mmu-ish/like) and relatively very high clock rates, etc.   Relatively large flashes and sram.  and physical sizes that are on par with full blown phone cpus.  and not too far on price with full blown cpus.

You use an mmu because you can get one for a few bucks and it can do some tasks very well using very little power, often battery power for a year or more.  Your computer has a number of them, as to countless other appliances and tools in your house that have a battery or plug in the wall.  You dont necessarily need an OS because the task(s) arent that complicated.  You want to do complicated things you use something more complicated.

We have such a wide array of choices today.  You put an mcu say in your mouse and keyboard, with hardware doing most of the usb protocol.  Then you may have another layer of logic which might have an embedded mcu in that to save on silicon development and other reasons, take ethernet for example, 8051s and z80s are popular in phys and macs, but you wont see this advertised or even mentioned, just that some binary blob is required for it to work and you have a couple-three options to get that binary into the part so that it can work.  We know from an apple laptop hack how smart the batteries are, there is a processor with some flash and firmware there too.  We now know that intel x86s have another management processor to help manage the part.

Thanks to phones we can get a wide array of older and current full blown linux/other operating system capable processors for fives of dollars, that can perform phone or set top box or other type tasks.  Thats blurring the high end mcu area.

The term embedded is too broad, the term operating system is too broad.  Generally your microcontrollers do not have a full mmu which today is heavily used to create what we call operating systems.  But the processors of the past that were used to invent the term operating system didnt all have nor use mmus and those were considered operating systems as well.   mmus generally use some form of non-volatile storage for the application code, some technology of rom (flash, eeprom, prom, etc) and for cost reasons and other these are relatively slow, your cpu is fed with MUCH faster ram than the mcu.  a number of mcus the flash at best is half the system clock rate, and for many if there is a pll which you can use to speed up the part the flash doesnt get any faster so you get to where the flash is a third of the processor clock, then a quarter.  and usually there is no cache, at best a prefetch buffer that covers linear execution of instructions, but hurts performance/latency if you branch, which you do often.  Yes there are some mcus that are now showing up with caches, but notice the price and size difference, these are not the $1-$2 parts.  (and yes some designs allow you to run out of ram, and often the ram is able to run at the cpu clock speed without any wait states).  Its not about latency.

The older architectures were not pipelined, had one register or a few, were worse than using a microcoded CISC processor it took many clocks to do anything useful.  It is not about latency.

Where you have time critical problems to solve, MCUs tend to solve that in logic for you.  Its not about latency.  Granted there is some well known code for the attiny that does USB without a USB controller, on my bucket list to dig through that some day.

Anything you can do with an operating system you can do without an operating system.  surf the web, play video games, etc.  The operating system doesnt make the task easier it just helps break it into manageable building blocks.  And this modular approach does very much cost in every way, binary size, memory consumption, overall performance including latency.  Modern operating systems rely heavily on processor modes (isolating an application from the kernel) and MMUs to keep the applications from poking into other peoples memory spaces.  caches simply try to compensate for the performance due to bloat, not required.  dram is simply cheaper memory, not required.  so if that is your definition of an operating system then no mcus generally dont have true protected/application modes nor mmus, not to mention not enough flash nor ram to hold an operating system.  But what an mcu does have even a $2 is more resources and performance than the first couple desktop computers I owned.  and the software those computers ran we called an operating system at the time.

Comment: This is great insight! So for an OS to 'exist' there has to be MMU in the hardware, which isolates individual processess for multi-taking? Also the "need" for an OS is merely for convenience (modularization and abstraction)?

Comment: It doesnt "need" to be there, but an MMU as we have them available and use them today along with processor modes allow the operating system to isolate applications into their own protected virtual memory, if they go out of bounds then the system will catch that.  It also makes it very easy to allocate memory for these applications as the mmu can make fragments of physical memory look linear on the virtual side.  Historically none of this was required, but it is used and relied on heavily today for the mainstream full blown OSes.

Comment: in some cases/designs an RTOS which is an OS.  doesnt have these requirements.  some can/do simply build all the applications in with the OS at build time, dont have to have virtual memory spaces that start at 0x00000000 for each application, etc.   and you will find a number of the mcus today have a ported rtos, freertos if nothing else.  not all can support that due to resource contraints but the ones that can often have that available. in the chip vendors best interest to have a port to pull in those customers.

Comment: task/application/whatever term you like.  anytime you want to isolate one chunk of code from having access to another or to keep a bug in that code from running out of its allocated space.  it also helps with virtualization, you can intentionally have it go out of bounds to access a virtual device, then operating system doesnt handle that as an error it instead virtualizes the device such that the application thinks it is talking to a real device.

Comment: each OS has its own design, features, rules of course, no reason for any two of them to do the same thing the same way.

Comment: I got much clearer picture now as this gave me a direction on what to pursue for my project. Please do care to take a look into [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/550195/real-time-linux-for-motion-control) if possible.

Answer (score 6):

> I was told by some developer that embedded controllers are task specific devices that requires low latency which processor based devices cant offer due to OS overhead.

That's one reason to use MCUs (microcontrollers). There are other reasons too, such as lower cost, smaller physical size, lower power draw. Think about all set-top boxes, smartwatches, dishwashers, car dashboards, etc.

> microcontrollers without OS

Note that it's common for microcontrollers to run special "embedded" OSes with only the most basic functionality such as memory management, task scheduling and some light hardware abstraction. These are often geared towards giving guaranteed timing, then calling themselves a real-time operating system (RTOS). These OSes are commonly compiled together with the application into a single binary, thus not really resembling the role of a PC OS where applications are separate.

I would say that only microcontrollers with 32 KB RAM or less are often programmed "bare-metal", without any OS library. Embedded OSes are used up to perhaps a couple of megabytes of RAM.

> Can the basics of functionality such as web surfing device be designed purely using microcontrollers without OS.

In this context, web surfing is far from being basic functionality. It requires TCP/IP communication, processing large images, running Javascript, rending to a high-resolution display, etc. While early attempts at mobile browsing was possible on non-smartphones using WAP, and text-based browsing is possible, I'd say in general this functionality is well into the processor domain, using many megabytes or RAM.

If the device has such powerful hardware, there's just no reason to forego the convenience of an OS. Once you programmed your bare-bone system as a browser, you have recreated the OS functionality anyway. That said, I think the OS could be a small embedded OS and not necessarily a full Android/iOS system.

An important factor is how much engineering you're willing to do to push a lot of functionality into a small piece of hardware. It can be year's worth of work to fully optimize the power of an embedded system by rewriting commonly available software just to make it a little smaller or faster. You could buy a lot of more powerful devices for that money.

Comment: +1 Very nice answer.

Comment: +1 Indeed a concise explanation!

Answer (score 2):

Though the line is blurring, microcontrollers have also traditionally sacrificed increased throughput for decreased latency, not just in the OS (if they run one at all) as mentioned, but also in hardware features. MCUs traditionally have omitted hardware features that increase throughput at the expense of latency and determinancy.

Such features include things like branch prediction, pipelining, external memory, cache, and memory management units (which tend to be required for an OS). These things have a tendency to either increase the worst-case time it takes to respond to interrupts and  make the worst case execution times less predictable.

Theoretically, you could implement pretty much anything on a microcontroller given enough speed and memory without the need for an OS or any of the fancy throughput features. However, bare-metal programming implies tailoring your code specifically for the hardware and at some point this becomes impractical for multiple reasons.

One reason is because you would have to, more-or-less, tailor all your code to the specific device, every time (and sometimes to other code running at the same time in a multi-tasking system)

Another reason is when you have multiple applications written by multiple people that need to run simultaneously on the system. In bare metal, they would have to coordinate with each other for these applications to be able to properly run.

An OS deals with both of these problems. An OS allows people to not have to coordinate their code with other people's applications (or unknowable future applications!). They all just collectively worry about the predictable OS and the OS runs the middleman to coordinate everything. This portability also allows software that should be relatively hardware independent, but very development intensive to be-reused without needing re-tailor it to the hardware every time. Imagine needing to tailor your web browser each time it has to run on a different processor.

Note that there does exist real-time operating systems (RTOS). Unlike something like Windows or Linux which prioritizes high average performance at the expense of guaranteed worst case performance, an RTOS prioritizes predictable  worst-case performance at the expense of high average performance. Windows or Linux offers high averages, but very low lows. This is not acceptable in an RTOS where an output that comes too late is useless. If your mouse cursors lags by one second every so often, no big deal but f your airbag deploys 250 millseconds too late just once, it might as well not fire at all. So an RTOS attempts to alleviate multi-tasking and development time for real-time systems.

Trying to code very sophisticated tasks in bare-metal is a bit like trying to code everything in assembler. You technically can get maximum performance and you actually have less limitations and more control. You actually have more freedom to do anything. It will just take you infinite time to development.

Comment: Makes so much sense, so RTOS gives less priority on multi-tasking and more on the task whose completion time is critical, right? so I guess we can create a rough hierarchy where at the bottom MCU based systems with almost no multi-tasking, RTOS with somewhat multi-tasking and at the top a regular OS, especially built for multi-tasking..

Comment: Or simply put, the "level of sophistication" that mandates "multi-tasking" encourages the use of microprocessors with OS, instead of microcontrollers, due to the need for "mmu" to isolate different processes from each other, as mentioned by @old_timer

Comment: @GENIVI-LEARNER it gives just as much priority on multi-tasking as any other OS. Not much point of an OS of any kind if you don't multi-task. But it cares about guaranteeing a predictable worst-case completion time more than high average completion time.